# What did I do wrong with this code for SImon game?

Tags: javascript, button, click

everyone! My name is Kate and I am a beginner in developing. Currently I am working on my test project, called "Simon game". I finished it but it doesn't work in a proper way. I checked the code million times, but can't find any errors. Please, look through it and if you can, please, help me to correct it.

```
var buttonColors = ["red", "blue", "green", "yellow"];

var gamePattern = [];
var userClickedPattern = [];

var started = false;
var level = 0;

$(document).keypress(function() {
  if (!started) {
    $("#level-title").text("Level " + level);
    nextSequence();
    started = true;
  }
});

$(".btn").click(function() {

  var userChosenColor = $(this).attr("id");
  userCLickedPattern.push(userChosenColor);

  playSound(userChosenColor);
  animatePress(userChosenColor);

  checkAnswer(userClickedPattern.length-1);
});

function checkAnswer(currentLevel) {

  if (gamePattern[currentLevel] === userClickedPattern[currentLevel]) {
     if (userClickedPattern.length === gamePattern.length) {
    setTimeOut(function () {
      nextSequence();
    }, 1000);
  }
} else {
    playSound("wrong");
    $("body").addClass("game-over");
    $("#level-title").text("Game over, Press Any Key To Restart");

    setTimeout(function () {
      $("body").removeClass("game-over");
    }, 200);
    
    startOver();
  }
}

function nextSequence() {

  userClickedPattern = [];
  level++;
  $("#level-title").text("Level " + level);

  var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
  var randomChosenColor = buttonColors[randomNumber];
  gamePattern.push(randomChosenColor);

  $("#" + randomChosenColor).fadeIn(100).fadeOut(100).fadeIn(100);
  playSound(randomChosenColor);
}


function playSound(name) {
  var audio = new Audio("sounds/" + name + ".mp3");
  audio.play();
}

function animatePress(currentColor) {
  $("#" + currentColor).addClass("pressed");
  setTimeout(function () {
    $("#" + currentColor).removeClass("pressed");
  }, 100);
}


function startOver() {
  level = 0;
  gamePattern = [];
  started = false;
}
```

I don't understand why the website doesn't react to a click on a button.
I check the button section, everything seems fine ‍♀️

Comment: So is there any errors in the developer console? Did you add console.log lines to verify things are being called? Did you verify it is finding the elements you are assigning click events too?

Comment: Just glancing, your developer tools is going to have an error message. Running it through EsLint `Error 20:3 'userCLickedPattern' is not defined.  (no-undef)` https://eslint.org/play/ Any good IDE should have pointed this error out. Learn to use your developer tools.

Comment: Learn about [how to debug small programs](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs). Use the [browser console (dev tools)](//webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`), read any errors.

Comment: Thank you, guys. I found an error. I should've used developer console at once.
There was a capital L after C in "userClickedPatter". So stupid ‍♀️, but it was hard to notice.